# Example of File System Search using apache solr 4.0

Tags: solr, full-text-search

Hi My Requirement is that: I have to create an web application where a search text and button will be there and when I enter some text to search it should search into my local file system on windows like: C:/ drive and lists and display these files that contains the matched text. It is like windows 8 file system search. Can anybody help me on these??? I new to Solr. 
I configured apache-solr-4.0.0 with Tomcat7 and JDK 7.
Please Help with some example. You can send me any sample application on shubhankar.sarkar@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [ManifoldCF](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html#What+Is+Apache+ManifoldCF%3F), which has a file system adapter and indexes into Solr. Otherwise, you have to build your own crawler, make decisions on what file types to index, etc.